# C++ : Cannot return a pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to have a function return a pointer to the smallest Cell in a linked list, where Cell is a struct. The function is giving me errors saying that the function is missing a type specifier. Any help is appreciated.

.h file

```
private:
// TODO: Fill this in with the implementation of your doubly-linked list
// priority queue.  You can add any fields, types, or methods that you
// wish.
struct Cell {
    string value;
    Cell * next;
    Cell * prev;
};
int count;
Cell * root;
void clear();
Cell * getSmallestCell();
```

.cpp file

```
Cell * DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue::getSmallestCell() {
Cell * smallest = root;
for (Cell * i = root; i != NULL; i = i->next) {
    if (i->value < smallest->value) {
        smallest = i;
    }
}
return smallest;
```

}

Comment: Can you not dual-tag C and C++? It is confusing in order to provide a good answer.

Comment: @JVApen C was never in question here.

Comment: It was tagged before your edited it. (See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38930881/revisions)

Comment: @JVApen C doesn't have a `private´ keyword, so I was sure to remove the c tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are right! I was glad you removed it, though I was asking Nathan at the same time you were removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Cell* DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue::getSmallestCell()
```

it should be

```
DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue::Cell* DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue::getSmallestCell()
```

or (since C++11)

```
auto DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue::getSmallestCell() -> Cell *
```

as `Cell` is a inner type of `DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue`.

Comment: Thanks. How come I don't have to specify the scope of Cell if I use it internally inside other functions?

Comment: If you use it in member method of `DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue`, you are in correct scope. Inside free function, you will have to use `DoublyLinkedListPriorityQueue::Cell` instead of `Cell`. (good use case for `auto` to shorten that type BTW).